# Errors encountered when installing Google Earth on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, debian

I need to install Google earth in my computer.I downloaded the 64 bit .deb package of Google earth and tried to install it using the following command
`sudo dpkg -i google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb`
But i get the following error

```
mala@mala-Aspire-F5-573G:/tmp/mozilla_mala0$ sudo dpkg -i google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 302542 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-earth-pro-stable (7.3.0.3830-r0) over (7.3.0.3830-r0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-earth-pro-stable:
 google-earth-pro-stable depends on lsb-core (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-earth-pro-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-earth-pro-stable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error shows you a dependency issue:

```
google-earth-pro-stable depends on lsb-core (>= 3.2); however:
Package lsb-core is not installed.
```

Google Earth requires the package `lsb-core` but it is not installed on your system.
Since this package is in the Ubuntu 17.04 repos, simply run `sudo apt-get install lsb-core` to install lsb-core. Then you can run `sudo dpkg -i google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb` again to install.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @MalaPokhrel Since this worked for you, you should click the check mark next to the answer. This is known as "accepting" the answer.